# php mysql database connection error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code that gets user login details from a html form:

```
  $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = "select username from users where user='$_POST[username]' limit1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo result;
```

But when I run it, i seem to be getting these errors:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local
>   MySQL server through socket '/directory omitted' (2) in
>   /directory omitted on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in
>   /directory omitted on line 10

Can anyone please help out? thanks very much!

Comment: You  are mixing `mysql_*`and `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed `mysqli` with `mysql` so there's a lot of typos

Code should be:

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $u = $_POST['username'];

 $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user='$u' LIMIT 1";
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['username'];
 }
```

Hope it worked.

Or if you need all rows printed it should be:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

Comment: No problem at all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select username from users where user='$_POST[username]' limit1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

These lines should be Like the following

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user='".$_POST['username']."' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```